# Threejs positioning 3D objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

I have a 3D Scene with three js that looks Like this:
[image: real image]

But I want to change it to something like this: 
[image]

The coloring, stars, and texture are not important, all I want is for the Earth shape to be shown as a half sphere from the bottom, I tried changing the Earth y position but it also changes how it looks because of the Perspective Camera

here is my code, it is a NextJs component but I believe the code wont be that different:

```
'use client'

import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import * as Three from 'three'

const Earth3D = () => {
  const canvas = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    let mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 }
    let target = { x: 0, y: 0 }
    let requestAnimationFrame: number

    /**
     * Three js
     */
    const scene = new Three.Scene()
    const clock = new Three.Clock()
    const textureLoader = new Three.TextureLoader()

    /**
     * earth
     */
    const earthObject = new Three.SphereGeometry(0.65, 64, 64)
    const earthTexture = textureLoader.load('/images/texture/earth-texture.jpg')
    const earthMaterial = new Three.MeshStandardMaterial({ map: earthTexture })
    const earth = new Three.Mesh(earthObject, earthMaterial)
    scene.add(earth)

    /**
     * light
     */
    const whiteLight = new Three.PointLight(0xffffff, 8)
    whiteLight.position.set(-1, 0.5, 2)
    scene.add(whiteLight)

    /**
     * camera
     */
    const camera = new Three.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100)
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 10)
    scene.add(camera)

    /**
     * renderer
     */
    const renderer = new Three.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas.current as HTMLCanvasElement, alpha: true })
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))

    /**
     * window resize handler
     */
    const resizeHandler = () => {
      // Update camera
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

      // Update renderer
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
      renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler)

    /**
     * window mouse move handler
     */
    const mousemoveHandler = (e: MouseEvent) => {
      mouse.x = e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2
      mouse.y = e.clientY - window.innerHeight / 2
    }
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveHandler)

    /**
     * animating
     */
    const tick = () => {
      // camera positioning
      if (window.innerWidth < 500) camera.position.setZ(3)
      else camera.position.setZ(2)

      target.x = mouse.x * 0.001
      target.y = mouse.y * 0.001

      // Update objects
      earth.rotation.y = 0.5 * clock.getElapsedTime()

      // update object by mouse move
      earth.rotation.x += 0.025 * (target.y - earth.rotation.x)
      earth.rotation.y += 0.5 * (target.x - earth.rotation.y)

      // Render
      renderer.render(scene, camera)
      requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
    }
    tick()

    // removing the window functions
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeHandler)
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveHandler)
      window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestAnimationFrame)
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas ref={canvas} className="relative w-screen h-screen outline-0" />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Earth3D
```

Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/three-96k3mg?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqy90j4y0008356md6czmrrp%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqy90j4y0003356mzcf1wpbc%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqy90j4y0005356mn2zgy9du%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqy90j4y0007356mjdm92htf%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B47.85559746500986%252C52.14440253499014%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqy90j4y0003356mzcf1wpbc%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqy90j4x0002356mziujis2c%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqy90j4y0003356mzcf1wpbc%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqy90j4x0002356mziujis2c%2522%257D%252C%2522clqy90j4y0007356mjdm92htf%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqy90j4y0006356m3zdboy0i%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqy90j4y0007356mjdm92htf%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqy90j4y0006356m3zdboy0i%2522%257D%252C%2522clqy90j4y0005356mn2zgy9du%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqy90j4y0005356mn2zgy9du%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqy90j4y0004356meiwqv19i%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqy90j4y0004356meiwqv19i%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A14.947916666666671%257D)

Comment: Can you provide sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try play with `y-axis` and relation to it adjust `FOV`.

```
const camera = new Three.PerspectiveCamera(
      25,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.1,
      100,
    );
    camera.position.set(0, 0.6, 10);
    scene.add(camera);
```

But if for some reason you don't want to manipulate the camera, you can play with the position (as you mentioned), but to make the Earth look like the one in the picture, without deformation, you also need to use `scale`. And when these two parameters are combined you will achieve the desired effect.

```
const earthObject = new Three.SphereGeometry(0.65, 64, 64);
const earthTexture = textureLoader.load("/earth-texture.jpg");
const earthMaterial = new Three.MeshStandardMaterial({ map: earthTexture });
const earth = new Three.Mesh(earthObject, earthMaterial);
scene.add(earth);
earth.position.set(0, -1.2, 0);
earth.scale.set(2, 1.6, 2);
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/three-forked-8qlrwc?file=%2Fcomponents%2FEarth3D.tsx%3A30%2C32

Comment: do you think `PerspectiveCamera` as used is better to achieve it or `OrthographicCamera`?

Comment: It depends on what the camera is supposed _to do_... If the camera is just going to render this Earth, it doesn't really matter as long as you're comfortable with the settings. However, if the camera has to do something more, especially in 3D, perspective is desirable. The nature of `OrthographicCamera` is such that it is more suitable for 2D projections, making things _flat_, let say... For instance, if you want to have dynamic transitions of your camera between the Earth in the example and other planets in the planetary system, a `PerspectiveCamera` would be more appropriate in my opinion.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, i think it is good now